# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type when inserting date and time

Tags: python, sqlite, datetime

I am trying to insert date and time into a sqlite table.

Here is my code.

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

### Date Time ###
dt = datetime.now()
dates = dt.date()
times = dt.time()


def sql(date, time):
    ### CREATE DB
    con = sqlite3.connect("date.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    ## CREATE TABLE
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS d_t (datee, timee)")
    con.commit()
    ## INSERT DATA
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO d_t (datee, timee) VALUES (?,?)", (date, time))
    con.commit()
    ## VIEW DATA
    cur.execute("SELECT * from d_t")
    row = cur.fetchall()
    print(type((row[0][0]))) # Printing_Date_only


sql(dates, times)
```

But this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hridoy\Documents\GitHub\Covid19\datedb.py", line 26, in <module>
    sql(dates, times)
  File "C:\Users\Hridoy\Documents\GitHub\Covid19\datedb.py", line 18, in sql
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO d_t (datee, timee) VALUES (?,?)", (date, time))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

I don't want to insert the date and time as strings because I need to compare two dates later, and one of them will come from the database.

Kindly looking for solution of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with SQLite can be a little tricky when trying to store dates/times, and I don't think you can store a time (without a date).  Why not just store the date and time together as the complete datetime value?

The below code stores the datetime value and modifies the sqlite3.connect() call to make dealing with datetimes nicer (we'll get a datetime back when we query the database).  We also need to specify the type of the d_t table's "date_time" column as a SQLite timestamp when we create the table.

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

### Date Time ###
dt = datetime.now()    


def sql(dt_value):
    ### CREATE DB
    con = sqlite3.connect("date.db", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
    cur = con.cursor()
    ## CREATE TABLE
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS d_t (date_time timestamp)")
    con.commit()
    ## INSERT DATA
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO d_t (date_time) VALUES (?)", (dt_value,))
    con.commit()
    ## VIEW DATA
    cur.execute("SELECT * from d_t")
    row = cur.fetchall()
    print(type(row[0][0]))  # Print type of datetime
    print(row[0][0])        # Print datetime
    print(row[0][0].date()) # Print date
    print(row[0][0].time()) # Print time


sql(dt)
```

As an alternative solution, you may also want to try the "easy_db" library I wrote to help out with this kind of problem.  Just install it with pip:

```
pip install easy_db
```

Then we can accomplish the same task with less/cleaner code.

```
import easy_db
from datetime import datetime

### Date Time ###
dt = datetime.now()


def insert_and_read_datetime(dt_value):
    # Create and connect to SQLite database
    db = easy_db.DataBase("date.db")
    
    # Create "d_t" table and add one row of data to it
    # From our input dictionary, a "date" column is automatically created and
    # this column is given the SQLite timestamp type based on the type of dt_value
    db.append("d_t", {"date": dt_value})
    
    # Run a SELECT * query to pull the full "d_t" table
    # Returned data is a list with a dictionary for each row
    data = db.pull("d_t")
    print(type(data[0]["date"]))  # Print type of datetime
    print(data[0]["date"])        # Print datetime
    print(data[0]["date"].date()) # Print date
    print(data[0]["date"].time()) # Print time

insert_and_read_datetime(dt)
```

Best of luck with your Covid-19 project!